# Find functions f,g

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Find f,g where $g\circ f$ is bijective,but neither f nor g is.

There are also two other easier problems before this one, which I manage to solve they're
Prove that if $g\circ f$ is injective then so f is and 
Prove that if $g\circ f$ is surjective then so g is.

So considering those two problems I manage to figure out that f should be injective and g surjective and for example $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=x^3-x$, but cannot construct for solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that $f$ has to be injective and $g$ surjective. In fact if you start with *any* injective $f$ you can always find a $g$ which works (not unique in general). Example (assuming all functions on real numbers):

choose $f(x) = e^x$ (which is injective, but not bijective). Then you have to choose $g(x) = ln(x)$ for $x>0$, and anything for $x\le 0$. For example $g(x) = \begin{cases} ln(x)& x > 0 \\ 0 & else\end{cases}$